# How can I provide a checkbox to display name as 'anonymous'?

Tags: 7, entities, panels, users

When users register on my website, they have to fill in their name. However, not everyone wants his/her name to be displayed on his/her profile page. Therefore, I'd like to provide a checkbox "Show as anonymous" during the registration which changes the name to *anonymous* on the profile page. In other words, the checkbox **rewrites** the displayed name, as opposed to [Is there a way to let every user can choose (e.g. on registration) whether their field is private or public?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81411/is-there-a-way-to-let-every-user-can-choose-e-g-on-registration-whether-their/81417#81417), where the field is hidden.

I rewrote the profile pages with **user_view** in the Pages section and I'm using [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels).

How can I do that?

Comment: try this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85278/populate-fields-when-a-checkbox-is-clicked-on-a-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more text field to user entity, keep it hidden.While registering the user check if show as anonymous user field is checked save the hidden field value as anonymous else copy the user name field to hidden field.

You can do the above changes in [hook_user_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7).

Finally add this hidden field to your user view, instead of name field.

Comment: I created 2 rules (using http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28750/rules-module-how-to-check-if-a-single-on-off-checkbox-is-checked/28755#28755) instead of using the hook_user_presave(), but I'll accept your answer because you had the idea of adding a hidden field to the user account. Thanks!